# How can I create SQL query for duplicates AND compare those duplicates to each other in the same report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table called `Applications` and trying to create a report.  I am finding duplicates based on an `ID Number`.  Now I need to identify from the list of duplicates those who reapplied within 60 days

```
SELECT a.App_date, a.ApplicationID, a.FirstName, a.LastName,  a.ApplicationType, b.DenialCode,
FROM  Application AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
               cares_data AS b ON a.ApplicationID = b.ApplicationID AND a.App_date = b.App_date
WHERE (ApplicationID IN
                   (SELECT ApplicationID
                    FROM   Application AS c
                    GROUP BY ApplicationID
                    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))  )

ORDER BY ApplicationID
```

So if the `ApplicationIDs` match only display those that have `App_date` within 60 days of one another.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  Some other DBMS?  Can you tag it appropriately?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Why there is END in the end of your query? And what is the question here?

Comment: select * from Application A where exists (select 1 from Application b where a.applicationid=b.applicationid), something like this should work to find the duplicates.

Comment: @rory.ap edited the comment now. That was a mistake. Was thinking one thing and writing something else. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes this is in SQL server. There is an end because I copied it from the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can try to query all the people (Ids) who had reapplied within 60 days, group that result with another query, like you do in the code you post and query the data you need based on the Ids you have got with another query.

```
SELECT a.App_date, a.ApplicationID, a.FirstName, a.LastName,    
a.ApplicationType, b.DenialCode
FROM Application AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN cares_data AS b 
ON a.ApplicationID = b.ApplicationID AND a.App_date = b.App_date
WHERE (ApplicationID IN "QUERY_RETURNING_IDs_AFTER_GROUP_THEM")
```

If you post more information about your tables or the technology you're using, maybe I can say you something more precise.

Comment: Hello I'm building it in SQL Server as a stored procedure but I'm tweaking it in the query view until it returns the cases I need.

Answer (score 0):

-- create a table to store ApplicationID that shows up more than once and it's last application date.
-- select form application table joined to dupes table on ApplicationID and date being greater than last application date - 60 days.

```
;With dupes as (select ApplicationID, max(App_date) as last_app from Application  group by ApplicationIDhaving count(*) > 1)
select t1.*
from Application  t1
join dupes t2 on t1.ApplicationID= t2.ApplicationIDand t1.App_date > dateadd(dd,-60,t2,last_app)
order by ApplicationID
```